# Navigation Drawer and Multipane layout

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I want to develop an application which it's going to be used on tablet, but I want to develop it for mobile phones too. I've looking for information, and I think that I have to do it with to different layouts, one for small screens based on Navigation Drawer and another for large screens based on Multipane layout, but I don't know how I should do this, can anybody help me? Anybody knows a good tutorial?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following Tutorial, this is a navigation drawer which can be used on both mobile and tablet devices.

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: It's a good example, but what I really want to know is how create an application which uses Navigation Drawer when it's on portrait and Multipane layout on landscape. The example is good but uses Navigation drawer for both.

Answer (score 1):

Read [Supporting Tablets and Handsets](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html) and [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). Basically, you need layout folders with smallest-width qualifiers.